# ImageMagick: How to change transparent background to a color?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

Given an input image `sample.i.png` with a transparent background :

[image]

**How to convert its background into a file `sample.o.png` with background `rgb(160,160,255)`, opacity 100% (or 1).**

---

Answer used:

```
convert source.png -background "rgb(160,160,255)" -flatten out.png
```

Please +1 emcconville's answer !

Comment: The answer is to blend it over an image of the same size with a solid color, but I don't know how to do that specifically with ImageMagick.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [Mark Random's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208116/imagemagick-how-to-change-transparent-background-to-a-color/25208277#comment39259782_25208116). Create a background image with your color, and flatten the source image over it.

```
 convert -size 150x150 xc:"rgb(160,160,255)" source.png -layers flatten out.png
```

[image: example]

**Edit**
If you don't want to worry about image size, just change the background directly.

```
convert source.png -background "rgb(160,160,255)" -flatten out.png
```

Add the [-flatten](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#flatten) to re-set the background color

Comment: Seems too specific, if the file size change the command get broken.

Comment: I +1ed it, but I hope a more generic answer.

Comment: More generic example added